# big space between columns and footer with chrome only

Tags: css

big space between columns and footer with chrome only

but with firefox is good no problem

see my site in chrome: http://qass.im/themes/

code columns:

```
#columns{

-webkit-column-count: 3;
-webkit-column-gap: 13px;
-webkit-column-fill: auto;
-moz-column-count: 3;
-moz-column-gap: 13px;
-o-column-count: 3;
-o-column-gap: 13px;
-o-column-fill: auto;
-ms-column-count: 3;
-ms-column-gap: 13px;
-ms-column-fill: auto;
column-count: 3;
column-gap: 13px;
column-fill: auto;
```

}

footer code

```
.footer{
color:#555;
background: #fff;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ccc;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ccc;
  -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ccc;
   box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ccc;
   padding:15px;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
     -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -o-box-sizing:border-box;
   box-sizing:border-box;
    border-radius:5px;
   margin:0 auto;
    display:block;
     overflow:hidden;
     clear: both;
     height: auto;
    margin-top:40px;
      width:800px;
    text-align:left;
```

}

what is this space?

thanks.

Comment: Correct the errors in your HTML first: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fqass.im%2Fthemes%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: no error, this element 100% but not registered

Answer (score 0):

Add css reset to start of code.

http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Use this :).

Comment: Download the css script and then link it in head element before your css sheet :). It resets all elements to get rid of default HTML margins/padding etc...